# Retention policy work for previously uploaded Documents?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, retention

When I set a retention policy on my shared document library, to start a workflow to email authors who's document is older than 30 days, will this work on documents already in the library or only documents that have been uploaded after the retention policy has been established?

Comment: no it should work for ALL documents in the library that are older than 30 days

Comment: Thank you also, Will this occur at the exact time the items were created? So for Instance if today is 30 days for a document, will the email be sent at the exactly time it was created?

Comment: it will happen whenever the information management policy timer job is run for the farm.

Answer (score 1):

It should work for all the documents

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/77810)

Comment: He asked a question not a solution to a problem

Answer (score 0):

The information management policy should happen for all documents--whether they were created 30 days ago or 4 years ago, if the information management policy is applied and run that night --it will apply to ALL documents in the library. The emails themselves will be generated whenever the information management policy timer job is run for the farm.

Comment: IS there a way to change the time of when the information management policy timer job is run or is it standard?

Comment: Yes, just go to the information management policy timer job in Central Administration -> Monitoring -> Timer Job Definitions, once you find Information Management Policy, click it and it will tell you the time window it runs, which you can edit.